# Mule Parse Template Multiple elements

Tags: html, mule-component, mule-el

I have a set of orders and want to generate an html document with the orders, I want to use parse template for that but I do not know how this will work for multiple order items in the payload. I want to generate something like this:

```
     <html>
      <body>
            <table border=4>
            <tr>
                    <th>Order No</th>
                    <th>Order Description</th>
                    <th>Provisioning Date</th>  
            </tr>
            <tr>
                  <td>#[payload[0]['order_no']]</td>
                  <td>#[payload[0]['order_description']]</td>
                  <td>#[payload[0]['provisioning_date']]</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                  <td>#[payload[1]['order_no']]</td>
                  <td>#[payload[1]['order_description']]</td>
                  <td>#[payload[1]['provisioning_date']]</td>
            </tr>
               ...... to n orders
            </table>
    </body>
 </html>
```

This is what I am trying to accomplish. How can I achieve this with parse-template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MEL (Mule Expression Language) you can loop through each order and construct the html and dynamic values needed.

```
#[       
    String orders = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < payload.size(); i++) {
        orders += "<tr>";
        orders += "<td>" + payload[i]['order_no'] + "</td>";
        orders += "<td>" + payload[i]['order_description'] + "</td>";
        orders += "<td>" + payload[i]['provisioning_date'] + "</td>";
        orders += "</tr>"
    }
    return orders;
]
```

Comment: Can this be dynamic part be part of the template?

Comment: Yes, place it inside your template file after the header row.

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript for looping in parse template:

```
var addressList = #[payload]
for (var i = 0; i < payload.length; i++)
    document.getElementById('table').innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + addressList 
    [i].order_no + '</td><td>' + addressList [i].order_description + '</td> 
    <td>' + addressList[i].provisioning_date + '</td></tr>'
```